# Warning [NgxImageCropper] Could not find HammerJS - Pinch Gesture won't work

Tags: angular13, hammer, ngx-image-cropper

I am implementing the NgxImageCropper library in a project, but the following warning is displayed in the console

> Warning [NgxImageCropper] Could not find HammerJS - Pinch Gesture won't work

1. Look on stackoverflow for some help and almost all of it points to installing or configuring HammerJS.
2. I tried to import HammerModule in the app.module.ts, but the warning continues there
3. I also tried setting Hammer as a provider in the app.module.ts file, but the warning remains there.
4. Also, I tried installing HammerJS, but the warning is still there.

install "ngx-image-cropper": "^6.3.4", to "@angular/cli": "~13.1.4", "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0"